# Расстановка кавычек

Tags: javascript, html, синтаксис

Здравствуйте. JavaScript знаю на начальном уровне и столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не могу расставить в куске кода кавычки, точнее, если ставить кавычки как подсказывает логика, скрипт в итоге не работает. Нерабочий код:

```
$js .= 'chat.append("<span class=msg><span class=time>' . $value['time'] . '</span> <span class=nick><a href="javascript://" onclick="document.getElementById('textfield').value = this.innerHTML">' . $value['user_name'] . '</a></span>: <span class=text>'. $value['text'] . '</span></span>");';
```

Вся проблема в этом куске кода:

```
<a href="javascript://" onclick="document.getElementById('textfield').value = this.innerHTML">
```

Если кавычки там оставить так, то ничего не получается. Подскажите, как сделать это рабочим?
Спасибо.

Comment: Вы уверены, что скрипт не работает только из-за кавычек? =)))

Comment: Уверен :) Вопрос решен!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Экранирование кавычек

```
$js .= 'chat.append("<span class=msg><span class=\"time\">' . $value['time'] . '</span> <span class=\"nick\"><a href=\"javascript://\" onclick=\"document.getElementById(\'textfield\').value = this.innerHTML\">' . $value['user_name'] . '</a></span>: <span class=\"text\">'. $value['text'] . '</span></span>");';
```